# AMQP purge in PHP driver

Tags: php, rabbitmq, amqp

Why do i have to specify the queue name in this method? 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/amqpqueue.purge.php
i use constructor for define queue name like this:

```
    $this->queue = new AMQPQueue($connection);
    $this->queue->declare($queueName, AMQP_DURABLE);
```

ii is not neccessary to define queue name in methods like: get, ack, consume

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's an example of a badly designed interface. It looks like the designers of the PHP `AMQPQueue` class lumped a number of things together into one place rather than split them up into separate classes.

Methods relating to message consumption from like `get`, `ack` and `consume` relate to a specific queue and are (as you observed) tied to the queue passed in to the constructor. The other methods which are not queue specific (`purge`, `delete`, etc) are more administrative methods and belong in a separate class which does not take a queue name at construction time.